# OpenCL - <eof> parser at end of file

Tags: c++, opencl, nvidia

I'm building an OpenCL-augmented application. When I was originally using ViennaCL I've found that while it compiles its internal kernels, I end up with the following:

```
Stack dump:
0.      <eof> parser at end of file
```

I was quick to blame ViennaCL for failing me, so I've quickly thrown together a couple of OpenCL helper functions and attempted to compile a very simple vector addition kernel.

The steps that the program makes are:

- create a platform
- select a device
- create a context
- create a queue
- push some data to device
- **compile a kernel**
- enqueue the kernel
- wait for kernel to finish
- read back the data

After commenting out most of it, I'm left with the mandatory setup and the command to compile a kernel. The result is, however, still the same:

```
Stack dump:
0.      <eof> parser at end of file
```

This is the offending function:

```
void createProgram(std::string progstr)
{
    const char ** conv = new const char*[1];
    conv[0] = progstr.c_str();

    cl_int error = 0;
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, conv, NULL, &error);
    if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "Error creating command queue: " << oclErrorString(error) << endl;
        exit(error);
    }

    error = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "Error creating command queue: " << oclErrorString(error) << endl;
        exit(error);
    }

    char* build_log;
    size_t log_size;

    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &log_size);
    build_log = new char[log_size+1];

    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, log_size, build_log, NULL);
    build_log[log_size] = '\0';
    cout << build_log << endl;
    delete[] build_log;
}
```

`context` and `device` are defined and valid, `program` is a `cl_program`.

I'm currently testing with a stock vector addition kernel:

```
__kernel void vector_add_gpu (__global const float* src_a, __global const float* src_b, __global float* res, const int num)
{
    const int idx = get_global_id(0);

    if (idx < num)
       res[idx] = src_a[idx] + src_b[idx];
}
```

I do not have access to another OpenCL-capable device to verify whether this might be something that I'm doing wrong.

I'm at a complete loss now. I've googled up a single thread on an AMD forum that suggests this might be caused by bad drivers, but I'd like a second opinion.

Comment: What is your kernel code? Also, could you check the error code from clCreateProgramWithSource()? And, please dump the buildlog from buildProgram, otherwise we can't see the building problems.

Comment: I've added the kernel, the error checking and some code to read the log as reflected above. The problem is, there is no output from this function - the only output I get is confirmation that an NVIDIA platform was set up from code not posted here, then the lines with the stack dump, and then the code hard crashes, dying in nvcompiler.dll (called from OpenCL.dll originally), so no useful output is produced.

Comment: To eliminate some more code, you could try calling clBuildProgram() without a devicelist. Also, the dynamic memory allocation at the top of your function is not necessary. A simpler 'const char* c = prog.c_str(); clCreateProgramWithSource(..., &c,...);' should do it.

Comment: I had kind of a similar problem once (don't remember exactly), but in my case I read the kernel source file into a std::vector and passed it into clCreateProgramWithSource(). Unfortunately this did not append a '\0' terminator at the end of the vector. Maybe it's something similar with your progstr.

Comment: @vobject: I've read in the c++ reference that `std::string::c_str` is guaranteed to return a null-terminated `char*`. I've applied your suggestions; indeed when calling clBuildProgram without the devicelist it compiles fine. My question is therefore as follows: will the effecting kernel still run on my chosen device if built this way, and if not, how can I work around my obviously broken devicelist?